# Can someone please help me fix this Xcode for a UICollection?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, nsuserdefaults, xcode7, nsdata

Can someone please help me fix this code? I am trying to expand the image that I click on in my collection view, but instead it expands the previous image that I selected. I think I am using `NSUserDefaults` incorrectly, but I am not sure. This is Xcode7 beta software.

```
import UIKit

class PortfolioDetail: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet var DetailImageView: UIImageView!

  @IBOutlet var DetailLabel: UILabel!

  var name: AnyObject? {

    get {

    return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("name")

    }

  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "BackgroundImage.png")!)

    DetailImageView.image = UIImage(named: name as! String)

    /* if DetailImageView.image == UIImage(named: "PortImage1") {

    DetailLabel.text = "Portfolio image 1"

  }

  if DetailImageView.image == UIImage(named: "PortImage2") {

    DetailLabel.text = "Portfolio image 2"

  }

  if DetailImageView.image == UIImage(named: "PortImage3") {

    DetailLabel.text = "Portfolio image 3"

  }

  if DetailImageView.image == UIImage(named: "PortImage4") {

    DetailLabel.text = "Portfolio image 4"

  }

  if DetailImageView.image == UIImage(named: "PortImage5") {

    DetailLabel.text = "Portfolio image 5"

  }

  if DetailImageView.image == UIImage(named: "PortImage6") {

    DetailLabel.text = "Portfolio image 6"

  }

  if DetailImageView.image == UIImage(named: "PortImage7") {

    DetailLabel.text = "Portfolio image 7"

  }

  */

  super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

  }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post your code as text, rather than a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You are using NSUserDefaults to get an image, but you are not saving any changes in it. You need also to update NSUserDefaults.
Also, next time please add your code as a text in a question.

Comment: I went back to edit my question with a text
thank you!

Comment: Do not store images or other data in `NSUserDefaults`. Save the image to a file.

Comment: https://ios8programminginswift.wordpress.com/2014/08/17/persisting-data-with-nsuserdefaults/

Comment: Thank you caleb for revising. I am new to this website.